# Why is this ajax request not appending to the show page at the bottom of the form in Rails 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have a Rails 4.1 controller action called "show" that renders a page with a contact form.  When the user hits "Send Now" on the contact form, I want a message notification that will be appended to the "#participant_notification" div id.

Now, when I have all the form fields filled out correctly, a new kite detail is created in the database, however a success message is not appended to #participant notification in the show.html.haml page.  Neither is an error message.   What is going wrong?

**show.html.haml with form:**

```
= form_for @kite_detail, as: :kite_detail, url: send_wind_questions_path, html: { method: :post }, remote: true do |f|
  %p Send questions about this kite to us
  .input-group
    %span
      %i.fa.fa-user
    = f.text_field :full_name,  placeholder: "Full Name" 
  .input-group
    %span
      %i.fa.fa-envelope-o
    = f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email address" 
  .input-group
    .left
      = f.radio_button :message, "I would like more information about this kite."
    %div.right I would like more information about this kite.
    .left
      = f.radio_button :message, "I, or someone I know would be interested in participating in this kite."
    %div.right I, or someone I know would be interested in participating in this kite.
    .left
      = f.radio_button :message, "I would like to collaborate with the designer."
    %div.right I would like to collaborate with the designer.
  = f.submit "Send Now", class: "kite-form-button", id: "participant-kite-form"
#participant_notification
```

**I also have a controller action send_wind_questions**

```
 def send_wind_questions
    @kite_detail = Kite.new(kite_detail_params)
    if @kite_detail.save
      puts "success"
      flash[:success] = "Your message has been sent."
    else
      puts "error"
      flash[:error] = "You didn't specify name, email, or some other error occurred."
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

**Here is my ajax javascript:**

```
$('form#new_kite_detail').submit(function() {  
    var valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(valuesToSubmit);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send_wind_questions", 
        data: valuesToSubmit,
        dataType: "JSON", 
        success: function(response) {
          $('#participant_notification').append('<p>You have successfully submitted your message.</p>');
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
          $('#participant_notification').append(request.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false; // prevents normal behaviour
});
```

Comment: when you look at the javascript console... do you see any errors?

Comment: I only see *GET http://localhost:3001/assets/underscore-min.map 404 (Not Found)* and *http://localhost:3001/images/some-icon.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*, neither of which is related to the issue (I think).

Comment: Often if a JS resource doesn't load then other javascripts don't properly run (even if they're not directly related), so it's worth checking out that one (the image you can probably ignore)

Comment: In your rails server log - do you get notification that the AJAX actually succeeded in sending a request?

Comment: Yes, I see an *SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "kite_details"** and I have logged into my development console and checked an object was in fact created.  So the request succeeds in creating the database object...

Comment: I'm not highly familiar with this stuff... but is there some kind of `respond_with :success` equivalent for a js response?rather than a render nothing for both success and error cases?